# Subquery multiple rows oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing these values:

```
╔════╦═══════════════╗
║ ID ║     TYPE      ║
╠════╬═══════════════╣
║  1 ║ FUEL PUMP     ║
║  2 ║ FIRE ALARM    ║
║  3 ║ FIRE PUMP     ║
║  4 ║ SAFETY SHOWER ║
╚════╩═══════════════╝

(query is: SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM EQUIPMENT)
```

And a query which returns the following:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╗
║    Room     ║ Equipment ID ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ Locker Room ║            1 ║
║ Hallway     ║            1 ║
║ Foyer       ║            2 ║
║ Office 1    ║            3 ║
║ Office 2    ║            2 ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

I have tried to make the EQUIPMENT.TYPE field display by using a subquery within the SELECT and WHERE statements of the query which generates the above table. However, I am getting the:`ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"`. I asusme this is because the EQUIPMENT ID value is returned more than once.

Is it possible to do this with a join?

Comment: Please show your query, and the expected output.

Comment: @Gary_W Thanks for your reply. I have managed to sort it. My wording of the question gave it away. I need a join not a sub query!

Answer (score 0):

```
select room, type
from equipment join rooms 
on rooms.equipment_id = equipment.id
```

Assuming the other table is called ROOMS.